# jquery access nested div

Tags: jquery, class, html, nested, addition

Here is my question. I am having this simple menu.

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <ul>
        <li> <a id="home" href="home.html"> home </a>           </li>
        <li> <a id="profile" href="profile.html"> profile</a>   </li>       
    <ul>
</div>
```

and I wanna to use jQuery to add a class ".active" to the **a tag** with the **id="home".**

What I am writing is:  `$('a#home').addClass("active");` but is not working. 
How can I access this nested tag and add some class??

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!
Thanx

Comment: could try just using the id: $("#home").addClass("active");

Comment: its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/8dfug/

Comment: try putting your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code here  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical mistake is to put your jQuery code in the header, but not wrapped in a ready event.

Make sure you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a#home').addClass('active');
});
```

see here for a live test: http://jsfiddle.net/QdVLs/ (remember jsfiddle automartically wraps any code in a ready method like above)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put use it after document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#home').addClass("active");
});
```

The reason can be when your javascript is executed the dom may not have created the element `a#home`/`#home`. This case can be handled using the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method as shown above.

You can test the case by just adding a `alert($('a#home').length)` statement before your code. It should alert `1` else you can try to use the `ready()` and try again, this time put the `alert()` inside the `ready()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`$('a#home').addClass("active");` should work.

Do you have other element with the same id ?

Where did you put this code ? (It should be executed after document ready event)

Comment: should have been a comment not an answer.